# How to Create CardView programmatically with two text views aligned vertically in it?

Tags: android, android-layout, cardview

Created a CardView instance and attached LinearLayout.LayoutParams, then added two TextViews to CardView, but TextViews overlap over each other instead of aligning one below the another

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);

card.setLayoutParams(params);
int margin = 10;
params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
// Set CardView corner radius
card.setRadius(15);
// Set cardView content padding
card.setContentPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
// Set a background color for CardView
card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFC6D6C3"));
// Set the CardView maximum elevation
card.setMaxCardElevation(15);
// Set CardView elevation
card.setCardElevation(9);

// Initialize a new TextView to put in CardView
TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
tv.setText(title);
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 17);
tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#006699"));


// Put the TextView in CardView
card.addView(tv);

TextView tv1 = new TextView(mContext);
tv1.setText(title);
tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10);
tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#006699"));

card.addView(tv1);
// Finally, add the CardView in root layout
rl.addView(card);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to create an object `LinearLayout` that will contain your `TextView`s and then add that `LinearLayout` to the `CardView` object